# Magento 2: Change hompage on login

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer-group

I am looking a way how can I change homepage route on specific customer group user login.
So basically problem that specific customer groups when logged in must see a different home page. How can this be done using events and observers. Also restrict that view only to that customer group. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a plugin for this.

**VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index">
        <plugin name="stackexchange_home" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Cms\Controller\Index\Index" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/Cms/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Cms\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Cms\Helper\Page;

class Index
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var Page
     */
    protected $pageHelper;

    /**
     * @param Page $pageHelper
     * @param Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        Page $pageHelper,
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->pageHelper = $pageHelper;
        $this->session = $customerSession;
    }

    /**
     * Renders CMS Home page
     *
     * @param string|null $coreRoute
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $coreRoute = null
    ) {
        
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $pageId = 4;
            return $this->pageHelper->prepareResultPage($subject, $pageId);
        }
        return $proceed($coreRoute);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked. Now i need to remove hard coded id and load page by identifier. Also add restriction to that page that only that customer group can access.

Comment: use \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH) to decide if customer is logged in

Answer (score 1):

I am not a magento2 guy. I can suggest you way how it could be done in magento 1.x.
You can change it accordingly for magento2.

- In module's config.xml, under `<frontend>` tag, define your event like `controller_action_layout_load_before` and define an observer's function to perform action on this event.
- Check customer group of logged in user and if it matches with the group, then change value of `web/default/cms_home_page` area programmatically.
  You may need to change above setting again for other customer groups also.
- It may be better not to change system configuration, but to redirect using:
  `header('Location: '.Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl(<your-other-cms-page-url>));` from observer when desired condition meets.

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Note: Terms used in this solution are from magento 1.x, not for 2.x. You need to make changes accordingly.