# How can I set a different home page depending on customer group (including people not logged in) on Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, controllers, plugin, cms-pages, magento2.4.4

I want to change homepage based on customer group.

I tried defining a plugin in this post [Magento 2: Change hompage on login](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121832/magento-2-change-hompage-on-login) , But it doesn't seem to work for me.

I could override the CMS default controller, but that seems overkill.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work for me" ? Do you have some errors or logs ?